# Django Cart Model with products - implementing quantity of items

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I've got a Cart, Product and a Entry model. What I'm trying to do is giving users the option to put more then one item in the cart and displaying the quantity in the checkout. 
I can get the chosen quantity over

```
quantity_input= request.POST.get('quantity-field')
```

and create a new Entry object within the cart_update()

```
Entry.objects.create(cart=cart_obj, product=product_obj, quantity=quantity_form)
```

which knows what cart and product it belongs to. 
But then I hit a wall in outputting it over the view since I'm only having a cart_obj as context not knowing how to also render the entry object in addition.

### Cart Model:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
        user        = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
        products    = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
        subtotal    = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)
        total       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)    
        count       = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

        objects = CartManager()
```

### Entry Model

```
class Entry(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True)
        eCart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True)
        quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

@receiver(post_save, sender=Entry)
    def update_cart(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        line_cost = instance.quantity * instance.product.price
        instance.cart.count = int(instance.cart.count) + int(instance.quantity)
```

### carts views.py

```
def cart_update(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    quantity_input= request.POST.get('quantity-field')

    if product_id is not None:            
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
        Entry.objects.create(cart=cart_obj, product=product_obj, quantity=quantity_input)
        cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)            
        added = True
        request.session['cart_items'] = cart_obj.products.count()        
    return redirect("carts:home")

def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    return render(request, "carts/home.html",{"cart":cart_obj})
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the first part of your question, you want to know how to pass more than one thing in the context part of your `return render(request, "carts/home.html",{"cart":cart_obj})`.

One way to do this is to store all the template variables you want in a dict and then pass the dict as the context, like so:

```
template_vars = {
   'cart': cart_obj,
   'entry': entry_obj,
   'some_var': some_value,
}

return render(request, "carts/home.html", template_vars)
```

Or you could do it the way you've got it right now, just adding stuff in:

```
    return render(request, "carts/home.html", {
        'cart': cart_obj,
        'entry': entry_obj,
        'some_var': some_value,  
    })
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Yes it helped. I used: entry_obj = Entry.objects.filter(cart=cart_obj) and then added in as another context object like you said.

Comment: @Tobstar If that answered your question, feel free to mark mine as the accepted answer. If it didn't answer your question, let me know what you're still wondering about.